# Can you unregister a shutdown function?

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to unregister a function (or all functions) set up with `register_shutdown_function()`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I do not believe you can. The only way to unregister a callback function is to wrap it in some sort of class that only actually calls it based on certain conditions. Like this handy function wrapper:

```
class UnregisterableCallback{

    // Store the Callback for Later
    private $callback;

    // Check if the argument is callable, if so store it
    public function __construct($callback)
    {
        if(is_callable($callback))
        {
            $this->callback = $callback;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Not a Callback");
        }
    }

    // Check if the argument has been unregistered, if not call it
    public function call()
    {
        if($this->callback == false)
            return false;

        $callback = $this->callback;
        $callback(); // weird PHP bug
    }

    // Unregister the callback
    public function unregister()
    {
        $this->callback = false;
    }
}
```

Basic usage:

```
$callback = new UnregisterableCallback(array($object, "myFunc"));

register_shutdown_function(array($callback, "call"));
```

To unregister

```
$callback->unregister();
```

Now, when called, it will return false and not call your callback function. There might be a few ways to streamline this process, but it works.

One such way of streamlining it would be to put the actual registration of the callback into a method of the callback function, so the outside world does not have to have knowledge that the method you have to pass to register_shutdown_function is "call".

Comment: In PHP 5.3 or later, you could use the magic method "__invoke", so that the object itself can be passed to `register_shutdown_function`.

Answer (score 5):

Hi I made a slight modification to the way my function worked as follows:

```
function onDie(){
    global $global_shutdown;

    if($global_shutdown){
        //do shut down
    }
}

$global_shutdown = true;
register_shutdown_function('onDie'); 

//do code stuff until function no longer needed.

$global_shutdown = false;
```