# Ignore non-fatal errors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

I am using Laravel 4.2.

I would like to ignore non-fatal errors. So far the only via method is described at [Disable laravel error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438560/disable-laravel-error-handler) but this has a couple of drawbacks:

1. Ignores all errors - not a good idea
2. By-passes Laravel error handling altogether - this can cause problem with future versions of Lavarel

The recommended way of handling errors is described at https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors (or https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors for those using Laravel 5). So, I can capture fatal errors using:

```
App::fatal(function($exception)
{
    return defaultError(500);
});
```

And this captures non-fatal:

```
App::error(function(ErrorException $exception) {
    Log::error($exception);

    return 'Oops! Looks like something went wrong';

});
```

The 2 gives me a demarcation between fatal and non-fatal. But for non-fatal I would like to display the actual page (which I am able to using [Disable laravel error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438560/disable-laravel-error-handler)) instead of 'Oops! Looks like something went wrong'.

In plain PHP this can be achieved using `error_reporting(0)` as described at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

Is this feasible in Laravel?

Thanks.