# Laravel 5.2 app - Debug is false but I'm still seeing PDO Exceptions

Tags: laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5.2 application which is displaying the typical 'Whoops, something went wrong' PDO error when it can't connect to the database (which includes the IP of the DB and the username/password).

In my app.php file I've got:

```
'debug' => false,
```

I've also tried clearing my cache on the server to see if it was still stuck on debugging, but that didn't do anything.

Any help with how to stop this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an `.env` file? If you are, try to change this configuration in this file.

Comment: @Laerte setting debug to false using the env file doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've finally got an answer...

Turns out I cached it using

```
php artisan config:cache
```

so I cleared it and now it works. I feel like a bit of an idiot after that..

Comment: Unfortunately none of these answers have worked for me. I plan to write what does work once I figure it out.

Comment: @Ryan did you figure it out?

Comment: @VolodymyrI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952236/470749 please upvote if it helped.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks. In the end I figure out that problem was related to my k8s setup, not to laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Go to config directory, edit **app.php** and on line 16 comment out `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),`

For commenting just add two slashes as below

```
//'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

Once you done that, it will now show simple generic error page if an error occurs.

Comment: Commenting out the debug option of app.php doesn't help, I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: It hides the data which you mentioned in question. Are you still seeing username and passwords etc in the error page?

Comment: That's correct, I'm still seeing the same error message with the username and password

Comment: Take a look on docs(https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#error-detail)  and this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438560/disable-laravel-error-handler?noredirect=1&lq=1) May be it helps you. In docs you can see a section error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in the other answers, messing with `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear` and `config/app.php` did NOT help me.

I'd forgotten that I'd customized my setup in Laravel 5.7.

1. To reduce confusion, temporarily delete any custom `/resources/views/errors/500.blade.php` you have.
2. Check to see if you've customized `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. I'd forgotten that I'd overridden the `prepareResponse` function.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but clearing the cache (`php artisan cache:clear`) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your server, `ctrl+c` on terminal and retype `php artisan serve` again.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You've to set `APP_DEBUG=true` inside `.env` file and inside config/app.php set `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)`