# Disable error reporting entirely in Laravel production?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I would like to disable error reporting entirely on production, because we have some very old code we still need to fix but for now does work (yes I don't like it either). We cannot fix everything in a few days, so we need to just supress the warnings and exceptions like we always did.

The real problem is that it already throws an exception on a simple lazy bug like (because var is not defined)

```
if(!$var) {
     // do whatever
}
```

**tried**

> APP_DEBUG=false
>
> APP_LOG_LEVEL=emergency

```
display_errors(false);
set_error_handler(null);
set_exception_handler(null);
```

But it still shows an `ErrorException`

> Undefined variable: script_name_vars_def

**edit**: The code works like this

**web.php**

```
Route::any('/someroute', 'somecontroller@controllerFunc');
```

**somecontroller.php**

```
public controllerFunc() {
    ob_start();
    require '/old_index.php';
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    return response($html);
}
```

This way we use Laravel routing without having to rewrite the old code immediately.

I know I can fix this warning very easy, but there are many, many more of these errors and we need to use Laravel routing now. Fix the problems later.

**ideas**

- Use some wildcard in `$dontReport`.
- Use a `@` suppression at the right place
- Can it be http://php.net/manual/en/scream.examples-simple.php

**edit to explain after which steps middleware didn't work**

1) create midddleware

```
php artisan make:middleware SuppressExceptions
```

2) Write it

*SuppressExceptions.php*

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    error_reporting(0);
    return $next($request);
}
```

3) Register

*laravel/app/Http/Kernel.php*

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
       \App\Http\Middleware\SuppressExceptions::class,
],
```

Comment: Have you tried `APP_DEBUG=false`?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo in my question, sorry. I enabled it again to copy and paste the warning :)

Comment: Well if you set APP_DEBUG=false and it still shows the error page with all the information, consider clearing the cache. There is no way supressing the error page if error occurs, unless you cover all functions with try/catch and maybe redirect

Comment: no then it just shows `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: You may need to use the error logs to track down where the issue is, and the use try/catch blocks to suppress and move past the messages.

Comment: @ThomasMoors What do you *want* it to do? If there's an error it's going to show an error page of *some* sort.

Comment: @ceejayoz It does not right now

Comment: @ThomasMoors also, have you tried to set `APP_ENV` to `production`?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot yes I did!

Comment: @ThomasMoors well, so probably env-file loaded with errors or maybe it has some misconfigurations. Try to print out settings of loaded env. Also maybe your settings overwritten by your `index_old.php` in the `required` expression.

Comment: Have you taken a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438560/disable-laravel-error-handler) question and answer?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I did not find it on the first try, thank you!

Comment: Did it help? If it did then either se should flag this as duplicate or I could write an answer here based on that question

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no access to the code until monday :)

Comment: Ok do tell me on Monday so we can proceed with the answer or flagging :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can change the error reporting. In fact, the framework provides a place to intercept the exceptions: `App\Exceptions\Handler`. By default the `render` method will convert the exception thrown to a HTML response. The `APP_ENV` and `APP_DEBUG` values will only change how this error response will render (details on the exception stack trace or not, basically).

Try changing the `render` method to

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ErrorException) {
        error_reporting(0);

        $kernel = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
        $response = $kernel->handle($request)->send();
        return $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This basically turns reporting off and then attempts to re-handle the request.
In the `if` clause you may check for any condition you want (the class of the exception, the severity, etc.). Catching `ErrorException` will probably cover your needs, but notice that you may not be able to recover from a fatal error this way.

Anyway, you should take that as a "proof of concept"... For non-idempotent requests, this "re-handle" approach is not good. Instead, just [create a Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#defining-middleware) with

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    error_reporting(0);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Same as before, fatal errors can't be recovered this way. But you can show a custom error message combining this middleware with the exception handler approach from before:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof FatalErrorException) {
        return view('fatal-error', ['exception' => $exception]);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: @ThomasMoors what's "didn't work"? You keep seeing the "Whoops" message? What's the exception? With this method I tried and successfully ignored some errors like undefined variable or division by zero

Comment: Yes, it does keep showing every single error. I will edit my question to explain the steps I tried from your answer.

Comment: @ThomasMoors saw your edit. That's exactly what I have. Are you sure the route is in the `web` group? Try doing `dd(something);` in the middleware method, just to make sure it is applying.

Comment: Yes I'm positive, have you tested your setup in combination with the code I wrote in *somecontroller.php*  using `ob_get_clean`? It might yield different results

Comment: @ThomasMoors wait, are you sure it's not the `require` that's failing? With `require '/old_index.php';` you are looking for a file at the root of the filesystem. Is there where you have it?

Comment: Yes, bacause after fixing the bugs for a certain "page" it shows up as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148226/discussion-between-alepeino-and-thomas-moors).

Comment: Why not do a 

`if (config('app.env') === 'production') {`

 kill the render method. Else, return the parent render method.

Answer (score 17):

Laravel debug settings is located in the `.env` file, in which you can set the debug option as follows:

```
APP_DEBUG = true
```

but...

Laravel also have config mechanism that located in `app.php` in the `config` folder, which defaults to:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

which tells Laravel to use the `.env` value, and defaults to `false`, but anyone with access to the file, can simply change it to:

```
'debug' => true,
```

so that your `.env` value gets ignored by Laravel.

Comment: If you have read the question and given answers, you could have know or deducted it's not as simple as forgetting the existence of the `.env` file. Next to that: env file has priority over the config file, the config file is the fallback value.

Comment: agreed, but what i told you is just that, it might be changed by someone who have access to the config file, like the last point of my statement?

Comment: It is **not** the case and even if it were: The .env file overrules the `app.php`. Are you satisfied now?

Comment: you are slightly wrong about the `.env` overrules the `app.php`, it overrules it because of the second point in my statement, and if it were changed, then the behavior would change. but if its not changed, then suits yourself, no need to be mad. i was merely assuming you are working as a team. looks like i was wrong

Comment: I do work in a team. The reason you agitate me is thst you give a low quality answer and you go to any lengths to defend it as a good answer.

Comment: I am giving you another place to check for, how is it poor quality (or good quality)? its not aimed to be, and clearly by the way you responded, you did not know how the config files are loaded, in which I gave you the information of it.

Comment: This solved my issue - I forgot to change the .env ;)  IMHO this is the 'correct' way of disabling public error reporting. OP was looking for a hacky way to not deal with some tech debt.  Real world can be a bitch.

Answer (score 8):

how i do is in

```
app/providers/AppServiceProvider
```

in boot function

```
public function boot()
{
   //add error reporting level
   error_reporting(0);
}
```

App Service Provider runs before Laravel compiles and therefore in boot function you can set error reporting to any level. it will set for all running scripts. You can open your app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php and in boot function add error_reporting(0/1)

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from it?

Comment: App Service Provider runs before Laravel compiles and therefore in boot function you can set error reporting to any level. it will set for all running scripts. You can open your app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php and in boot function add error_reporting(0/1)

Answer (score 4):

I guess your `php.ini` loaded from another place. So settings still not applied. Try to find correct location of `php.ini` (you can see information in the `phpinfo()`). Anyway, you can rewrite those parameters with yours in `index.php`:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

But as the @Davon says in the comment. Those settings will be overwritten by Laravel. So code above can be placed in your controller. But it will be dirty hack. So You have to find another way. Try to print your `.env`'s content. Maybe some setting is incorrect.

Comment: This won't have an affect on Laravel since Laravel resets error_reporting when the app is booted.

Comment: @Devon oh yes, indeed. Found it in `bootstrap()` method in the `HandleExceptions` class.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is that you are seeing the 'Whoops something went wrong' page, you could fix that with the answer @alepeino wrote:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862789/2777970

But I'd change the render method to:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if (!config('app.debug')) {
        error_reporting(0);

        return response('nothing', 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This render method (the parent) is the one that builds and returns the html for the "Whoops" page, so if you overwrite it, you should be cool.

To change de debug config, check if your config/app.php has the debug options using the ENV value APP_DEBUG, and on your production .env, check it's set to false (APP_DEBUG=false).

Comment: And about the bug that's causing it to display an error, you should use

`if (!isset($var) || !$var) `
So it checks if the variable exists before checking it's boolean value, so you won't get an error. But I think you may not wanna fix this or it's not as simple as you said, cause otherwise this question would be anotherone

Comment: I already fixed 1000+ instances of this "bug" haha, my solution btw is `$var = $var ?? null`

Comment: Nice, php7 features

Comment: This works partially: it stops rendering the rest of the page upon reaching the "bug".

Comment: But I don't get it, you still have content before? Or you get the php error?
To fix the php error shouldn't you fix it with the php.ini suggestion someone told? `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` ?

Comment: Can you show me a screen or a tinypaste of the output? I think it'll help a lot. And your desired result (empty with a 500 status?)

Comment: Desired result is routing with laravel, but output as if the file(s) was / were called directly. That's why I was using ob_get_clean

Comment: Oh.... I don't know how to help you with that... did ob_get_clean work? Cause it looks like you are trying to undo some printing... So I guess you are migrating to laravel instead of embedding php tags as it was before?

Comment: It does work, but now every soft-error / bug like using the check `!$var` (instead of (`!isset($var)`) will trigger an exception and even when turning of the render function of the exception still prevents the rest of the page from executing

Comment: So what about supressing erros? `error_reporting(0)` there I think might be too late, so why don't you add that error_reporting line on your `bootstrap/app.php` and see what happens?

Comment: I would suggest to debug it by standing before the error (on the code) and testing what kind of error_reporting type best suits your problem. Check 
[php error-reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for more options. Here you have more error configs to try out [php errorfunc.configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php). If you found your desired one (I recommend not to overdoit), add it to your bootstrap/app.php. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

The second line changes the value of 'display_errors' in the `php.ini` file

EDIT: Add more code to show how this has to be environment specific...

$env = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');

```
 switch ($env) {
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            $config = include __DIR__ . '/../app/config/config_prod.php';
            break;

        case 'staging':
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $config = include __DIR__ . '/../app/config/config_staging.php';
            break;

        case 'development':
        case 'local':
        default:
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $config = include __DIR__ . '/../app/config/config_local.php';
            break;
```

Comment: it has no effect for me at all, it still shows `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: can you show a little more code of what you're trying to achieve? Also, not that those that these changes have to be environment specific. See my edits

Comment: You may want to consider getting the environment with `config('app.env')` instead of calling `getenv`; if the configuration is cached, the call to `getenv` will return null instead of production, staging, etc.

Comment: This won't have an affect on Laravel since Laravel resets error_reporting when the app is booted, you'll need to modify the core framework HandleExceptions.php like shown in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel emphasizes error and warning free code, so the best way to handle this is just by making sure your code doesn't produce any errors, warnings, or notices.

**Update:  I do not recommend the below method for recent versions of Laravel.  Laravel now allows you to change exception handling in a non-vendor class: App\Exceptions\Handler as indicated by alepeino's answer.  A middleware can also be a better solution to disabling error_reporting.**

This previous answer is maintained for historical purposes but I don't recommend modifying vendor files.

---

If, however, you still decide to alter this behavior, you'll need to look in a file named HandleExceptions.php normally found at vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:

```
public function bootstrap(Application $app)
{
    $this->app = $app;
    error_reporting(-1); // change this line to your desired reporting level
    set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);
    set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);
    if (! $app->environment('testing')) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    }
}
```

Line 32 where error_reporting is currently set  to -1.  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php

**Of course, by modifying this code, you'll either need to prevent updates of laravel/framework or you'll need to verify this file on every update.**

After updating this code, you'll need to recompile your classes:

```
php artisan clear-compiled; php artisan optimize
```

Comment: I understand, but even changing it to `E_ERROR` it did not change anyhing whatsoever

Comment: Did you clear your application cache and compiled classes?

Comment: @ThomasMoors clear-compiled is what you want, cache:clear only relates to cached objects, not compiled classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in any function in your class as example:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
}
```