# getting 500 internal error at the start in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had php 5.6 which I unistall and put laravel 7.3 and then 7.2 and now 7.1. After fresh xampp and composer installation I run the project, It give me 500 internal error in the console which points to index.php.  I'm just trying to run a project downloaded from git. Can't run Laravel, phpmyadmin is working.

I also checked the log file.It says..

> [2020-04-12 19:48:50] production.ERROR: RuntimeException: The only
>   supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key
>   lengths. in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\hrm-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:43
>        Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\xampp\htdocs\hrm-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(27):
>
> Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->__construct('', 'AES-256-CBC')
>
> ## 1 D:\xampp\htdocs\hrm-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(746):
>
> Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
>   Array)

My xampp controll panel is showing 'x' mark under service module, so I think I havent installed xampp correctly, but then other non laravel project and phpmyadmin is working fine. 
 What might be the issue?

Comment: I think you need to generate a key. [Does this help at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370134/when-to-generate-a-new-application-key-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

```
php artisan confg:cache
```

Comment: I had other problem maybe xampp was not installed properly, untill I reached to this error, In php 7.3 I was getting count() expects parameter to be an array ..something like this.. untill I reach above error and your solution is working . thanks.

Comment: you should change it to sizeof since in php 7 it will throw this warning or ignore that error with @

Comment: Yes but also read that we should not do changes in vendor folder

Comment: No I didn't say change the vendor folder, if the problem is inside the vendor add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);` on the constructor of the contoller

Comment: Yes, but then which controller? Its not even loading index.php, how will it even reach controller?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806474/disable-error-reporting-entirely-in-laravel-production