# Phpunit : hadling the validation exception in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-testing

I have turned `throw Exception` in `handler.php` so that I can catch `exceptions` and see the `errors` but what happened is when I try to do the `validation checks` it throws me an exception which is correct but in my test case instead of catching the `exception` i'm asserting that the session has errors.

```
/** @test*/
    public function a_thread_requires_a_title(){

        $thread = make('App\Thread', ['title'=> null]);
        $this->post('threads', $thread->toArray())
            ->assertSessionHasErrors('title');
    }
```

Since, `validation error` is an exception so it throws me an exception because I've modified the `handler.php` file as

```
if(app()->environment() === "testing") throw $exception;
```

so, what I'm trying to do is change the env for this one test so that it wont throw me an 'Exception'

Comment: Put this at the top of your test method: - `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`

Comment: withoutExceptionhandling its already built in ?

Comment: @senty this method is not working for me.. I'm still getting the validation exception.? is there a way around?

Comment: Omg ..... there's withExceptionHandling as well.. sorry i was following old courses ... it was the opposite.. thanks a bunch man

Comment: :) No worries - happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 helper methods which you can write at the top of your test method:

`$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` and `$this->withExceptionHandling();`

> They are included in Laravel's 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithExceptionHandling' trait which is used by the abstract TestCase that you should be extending from your test. *([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655984/disable-laravel-exception-handling-for-tests/54411121#54411121))*

```
/** @test*/
public function a_thread_requires_a_title() {
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $thread = make('App\Thread', ['title'=> null]);
    $this->post('threads', $thread->toArray())
        ->assertSessionHasErrors('title');
}
```